# How do I terminate forked processes in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am trying to run several commands at the same time. I prepare it in a script by appending each command to a single command that would look something like

```
and=" & "
command=$command1$and$command2
eval $command
```

However, when I run this, each command is forked and completes correctly, but it then hangs at the command line and never returns me to the prompt.

Example (script run.sh). If the two commands are:

```
command1="echo 'Hello'"
command2="echo 'World'"
```

then the output is:

```
person: ./run.sh
Hello
World
## It Hangs here
```

instead of

```
person: ./run.sh
Hello
World
person:
```

so how do I terminate the forked processes, or have the script block until the forked processes complete?

Comment: `&` is not "and".  "and" is `&&`.  `&` backgrounds the process

Comment: Also, `eval "$command"` because otherwise it turns into `eval command1 & command2`, which is `eval command1` and `command2` separately.

Comment: @Shahbaz or worse yet, `$command1` and `$command2` might themselves get wordsplit upon expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your examples are simplified (since 'echo' should complete immediately and return to the prompt), you just need to background the second command.  IOW, try:

```
command="$command1 & $command2 &"
```

Note that I've removed your "and" variable, since it is mere obfuscation.  A single `&` is in no way an `and` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting output like this:

```
~/dev/other $ echo foo &
[1] 522
~/dev/other $ foo
▯ # blink, blink, blink…
```

In this case you *are* being returned to the prompt, but the prompt is appearing before `echo` completes, and thus the string to be `echo`ed is appearing after the prompt, followed by a newline. You can write your next command on that new line after the prompt, or just hit `enter` to get a new prompt.

If this is happening in a script, you can add the builtin `wait` to the end of the script to ensure that the script doesn't return the prompt before all of its backgrounded child processes are complete.

Comment: Thats exactly whats happening.. eval forks those processes and the script technically finishes so the prompt shows up before my commands finish.. thats the hanging.. I know I can just press enter, but I need the prompt to show up because the output from the commands is very complex and its not clear when its actually finished.

Comment: @user1566163 just add the command `wait` to the end of the script.

Comment: @user1566163 don't forget to upvote all helpful answers and mark the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your command should be like this:

```
command= $command1$and$command2$and
```